# KDE Application Launcher search not smart enough with different keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, kde, keyboard-layout

My system is running on KDE.

I'm using two keyboard layouts: English and Russian (Cyrillic).

KDE Application launcher is configured to activate its applet by pressing Meta key (Win key). Usually, I enter the search query immediately after pressing Meta key. Sometimes I forgot to change keyboard layout and search does not provide any results.

For example, I'm searching for Dolphin. I'm writing "Вщдзршт" instead of "Dolphin". Where "Вщдзршт" is Cyrillic symbols which are in the same places on the keyboard as English letters. Here is an example of such keyboard:

[image]

For Dolphin, I solved this in a very simple way. I added Cyrillic equivalent to a description of the Application. Here is how it looks like now:

[image]

My question is: Is there any way do it automatically for all applications? Or is there any settings for such things?

KDE Menu Editor
Version 5.8.7

Comment: Have you thought about binding a shortcut to meta key so when you press it it will change the layout to `en`? it might work... I don't have access to kde otherwise I would test it.

Comment: This is workaround, while I’m interested if it is naturally possible. May be there is a file where all descriptions are located. Then I could write a bash script to add cyrillic labels automatically.

Comment: Consider playing around `.desktop` files that might help you: `/usr/share/applications`